# How to expand a 2d array based on a number

Tags: python, arrays

I want that:

```
num = 3
array = [0,0,0,0,0]
```

become this:

```
array = ([0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0])
```

I've tried this:

```
array = ([0,0,0,0,0],)*num
```

and this:

```
array = [[0,0,0,0,0]]*num
```

but when I set the values, it sets it everywhere.

```
num = 3
array = [[0,0,0,0,0]]*num
print(array)
array[0][0] = 1
array[1][1] = 2
print(array)

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0]]
```

when it should be that:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `List Comprehensions` to build the `2D list` . The thing that you are doing is actually making `3(num)` references to the same list !! To understand it much better, consider this example

```
>>> a=b=[5]
>>> a[0] = 6
>>> a
[6]
>>> b
[6]
```

So use list comprehensions, so that all the inner lists are "**unique**".

```
num = 3
array = [[0,0,0,0,0] for i in range(num)]
print(array)
array[0][0] = 1
array[1][1] = 2
print(array)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```